# Get some elements from numpy array in reverse order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reverse

I need to generate numpy arrays getting elements in reverse order from another array.

### Toy example code

Lets say I use following toy example code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,5,8,13])
n = len(a)

for i in range(n):
    print a[n:n-i-2:-1]
```

I would expect that last print is a `[13  8  5  3  2 1]`, however I get an empty array `[]` as seen below:

```
>>> 
[13]
[13  8]
[13  8  5]
[13  8  5  3]
[13  8  5  3  2]
[]
```

### Fix

So I had to create below fix to my code within the `for` loop to get what I expect.

```
for i in range(n):
    print a[n-i-1:n+1][::-1]
```

Which means selecting the arrays from the original array and then reversing it.

### Questions

1. Why when I try `a[6:0:-1]` I get `[13,  8,  5,  3,  2]` but once I try `a[6:-1:-1]` I get an emtpy array `[]`? I would expect to get the whole array reversed as when you try `a[::-1]`.
2. Is the fix I implemented the way to go or there is something I'm missing here?

### Edit

The post [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) answers my first question but not the second one.

Comment: You might find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: What would you expect `a[6:5:-1]` to produce?

Comment: Then you really should read up on slice notation.

Comment: Sorry @ScottHunter I misread you question `a[6:5:-1]` would produce []

Comment: Then I guess the code I use in the fix is the way to go.

Comment: And -1 is a "shorthand" for the index of the last element (in this case, 5), so it should (and does) do the same.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly more elegant fix.

```
for i in range(n):
    print(a[n:-i-2:-1])
```

or even more elegant

```
for i in range(n):
    print(a[:-i-2:-1])
```

both print

```
[13]
[13  8]
[13  8  5]
[13  8  5  3]
[13  8  5  3  2]
[13  8  5  3  2  1]
```

It also demonstrates the rule that negative indices count from the top, which is why your original loop switches behavior when the stop index gets to -1.

Comment: This makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use below code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,5,8,13])
n = len(a)

l = range(n)
l[n-1] = None

for i in range(n):
    print a[n:l[n-i-2]:-1]
```

As performing `a[n:None:-1]` is same as `a[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Use **list comprehension** and get the results in one line:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,5,8,13])
n = len(a)

# use list comprehension here
[list(a[n:-i-2:-1]) for i in range(n)]
```

```
# [[13],
#  [13, 8],
#  [13, 8, 5],
#  [13, 8, 5, 3],
#  [13, 8, 5, 3, 2],
#  [13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1]]
```

In case you really need the exclicit for loop use this:

```
for i in range(n):
    print(a[n:-i-2:-1])
```